# What is the necessity for a karmic loop?

Tags: karma, moksha, creation

My understanding is that prarabdha karma affects the current janma, and the current janma's positive and negative karma cumulatively gets added to that prarabdha and the cycle continues ad infinitum, unless one breaks the cycle by attaining Moksha.

So what is even the necessity for starting such a karmic loop? Why couldn't all beings have the default state of Moksha when they began?

Comment: No need, it is because it is the Lord's sport...

Comment: In that case why couldn't Lord start the sport with all creatures having Moksha as their default state?

Comment: Moksha is your default state...you only have to realize it. You are free already, you were never bound. You have only hypnotized yourself into thinking you are bound.

Comment: Some body will hypnotize you to become something else for sport will you accept though  all are equal but God just for sport hyponetize somebody to be born differently (tree, animal).. why? than attribute partiallity God.. by default God is partial because for sport he his causing the harm to jeeva if you go by above Swamis Vishwananda statements

Comment: Karma is beginning less.  Only some souls (the nitya suris) are eternally free.

Comment: My question is why does one even need to have any Karma to begin with (less or more) , why cant the default be Moksha?

Comment: Each dimension of existence has its own manifestation Gunas. When Purusha comes in interaction with those Gunas, it starts to take birth in that dimension of existence and as it moves ahead in life, the manifestations Guna, atmosphere surrounding deludes the Purusha and it forgets who it is completely. The child in womb and until skull fully develops after birth the child is in oness with cosmos. But due to influence of Prakriti it gets deluded and hence karma happens.

Comment: @Vandan will put it simple, Karma is inherent like seed.. forget karma.. Think God as garderner with infinite no. of different type of seed he planted in the field and nurtured them.. the different trees are according to the seed nature (mongo, jackfruit and cactus) opium all plants trees are there but you cannot blame the gardner for sowing the seed, its only the seeds nature is expressed as Gunas and hence karma this whole world or universe root lies in one of the three Gunas.. that is why god is called thripada urthava uthaith purusha (in pursha suktham)

Comment: Precisely my point, why did the gardener even plant the various kinds of seeds, why did he even start the whole process ? What is the necessity to sow the seeds ? @PrasannaR

Comment: Take Gardner he plants seed to harvest, in between he can plant shrubs or whatever he many choose to ensure diversity in the garden. Gods harvest( Moksha prada) God is moksha prada and every mumukshu should be perform shadana to achieve the same.. shadana is very little when surrounding environment facilitates you to take up easily.. the same shadan is if done in kali yug and athestic times its results in exponential results @Vandan

Answer (score 2):

> So what is even the necessity for starting such a karmic loop?

**According to the Brahma Sutras, karma is beginningless; the Jivas who are trapped in samsara have always been in it.**

Ramanujacharya [has stated](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48204.htm) in his commentary on the Brahma Sutras:

> Although **the individual souls and their deeds form an eternal stream, without a beginning**, yet non-distinction of them 'is reasonable' (i.e. may reasonably be asserted) in so far as, previous to creation, the substance of the souls abides in a very subtle condition, destitute of names and forms, and thus incapable of being designated as something apart from Brahman, although in reality then also they constitute Brahman's body only. If it were not admitted (that the distinctions in the new creation are due to karman), it would moreover follow that souls are requited for what they have not done, and not requited for what they have done. The fact of the souls being without a beginning is observed, viz., to be stated in Scripture,'The intelligent one is not born and dies not' (Ka. Up. I, 2, 18); so also the fact of the flow of creation going on from all eternity, 'As the creator formed sun and moon formerly.'

So, one cannot attribute cruelty to Brahman, since creation is based on the Jiva's karma, which is beginngless.

> Why couldn't all beings have the default state of Moksha when they began?

There are 3 categories of souls according to Ramanujacharya's doctrine:

1) Nitya suris, or those who are eternally liberated

2) Muktatmas, or those who were once in samsara, but are now liberated

3) Baddhatmas, or those who are currently in samsara, and will be liberated

So, the only souls who have the default state of moksha are the nitya suris.

Answer (score 1):

In Rig Veda [I.164.20](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01164.htm) and in [3.1.1 of Mundaka Upanishad (page 51)](https://estudantedavedanta.net/Mundaka_and_Mandukya_Upanishads%20-%20Swami%20Sarvanand%20%5BSanskrit-English%5D.pdf), there was a mention about 2 birds perching on a branch of a tree.

> दवा सुपर्णा सयुजा सखाया समानं वर्क्षं परि षस्वजाते | तयोरन्यः पिप्पलं
>   सवाद्वत्त्यनश्नन्नन्यो अभि चाकशीति ||
>
> Two Birds with fair wings, knit with bonds of friendship, in the same sheltering tree have found a refuge. One of the twain eats the
>   sweet Fig-tree's fruitage; the other eating not regardeth only.

The first bird represents a **Jiva**, or individual self, or soul. She has a female nature, being a shakti, an energy of God. When the jiva becomes distracted by the fruits (signifying sensual pleasure), she momentarily forgets her lord and lover and tries to enjoy the fruit independently of him. This separating forgetfulness is maha-maya, or enthrallment, spiritual death, and constitutes the fall of the jiva into the world of material birth, death, disease and old age.

The second bird is the **Atma**, an aspect of God who accompanies every living being in the heart while she remains in the material world. He is the support of all beings and is beyond sensual pleasure.

---

According to scriptures, the God will be witness to all actions of the Jiva or soul, whether it indulges in sensual pleasures or spiritual pursuits, but does not give help unasked for.

So it is the Jiva or soul that indulges in sensual pleasures or materialistic tendencies and start accumulating karma.

According to the realised souls, everyone is divine, the only difference being the realised one knows it and ignorant one does not know.